# Timedelta in hours,minutes,seconds,microseconds format

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to make the timedelta to display time in `H:M:S:MS` format , i am able to display in `H:M:S` format using `datetime.timedelta` function like below

```
 print((datetime.timedelta(minutes=500)))

output: 8:20:00
```

How can i get the output as `8:20:00:00` in `H:M:S:MS`

Answer (score 2):

One way to go is using string formating:

```
d = datetime.timedelta(minutes=500)
print('%s:%s' % (str(d), d.microseconds))
# 8:20:00:0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add one:

```
print(str(datetime.timedelta(minutes=500))+':0')
```

Output:

```
8:20:00:0
```

Comment: @Techiesoft Now?

Comment: it need not be zero always, it has to calculate that,what if the minutes are in float say 765.254 so the output has to 12:40:5:4something