# How can I format timedelta microseconds to 2 decimal digits?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Running this

```py
import time
import datetime

timenow = time.time()
timedifference = time.time() - timenow
timedifference = datetime.timedelta( seconds=timedifference )
print( "%s" % timedifference )
```

I got this:

```
0:00:00.000004
```

How can I format trimming the microseconds to 2 decimal digits using the deltatime object?

```
0:00:00.00
```

Related questions:

1. [Timedelta in hours,minutes,seconds,microseconds format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55074401/timedelta-in-hours-minutes-seconds-microseconds-format)
2. [Formatting microseconds to two decimal places (in fact converting microseconds into tens of microseconds)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586943/formatting-microseconds-to-two-decimal-places-in-fact-converting-microseconds-i)

Comment: The too obvious (and wrong) solution would be to use string slicing.

Comment: Works like a charm! `timedifference = str(timedifference)[:-4]`

Comment: And as I said it was wrong, try with zero milliseconds

Comment: I already had seen it. I showed `0:0` or something like it. But it is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to format it yourself. A `timedelta` object contains `days`, `seconds` and `microseconds` so you'll have to do the math to convert to days/hours/min/sec/microsec and then format using python `string.format`. For your microsec, you'll want `((microsec+5000)/10000)` to get the top two digits (the +5000 is for rounding).

Answer (score 3):

Convert the timedifference to a string with `str()`, then separate on either side of the decimal place with `.split('.')`. Then keep the first portion before the decimal place with `[0]`:

Your example with the only difference on the last line:

```
import time
import datetime

timenow = time.time()
timedifference = time.time() - timenow
timedifference = datetime.timedelta( seconds=timedifference )
print( "%s" % str(timedifference).split('.')[0] )
```

generates:

```
0:00:00
```

Comment: got to admin it both elegant and simple (pythonic in my opinion)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to split the fractional part numerically and format it separately:

```py
>>> seconds = 123.995
>>> isec, fsec = divmod(round(seconds*100), 100)
>>> "{}.{:02.0f}".format(timedelta(seconds=isec), fsec)
'0:02:04.00'
```

As you can see, this takes care of the rounding. It is also easy to adjust the output precision by changing `100` above to another power of 10 (and adjusting the format string):

```py
def format_td(seconds, digits=2):
    isec, fsec = divmod(round(seconds*10**digits), 10**digits)
    return ("{}.{:0%d.0f}" % digits).format(timedelta(seconds=isec), fsec)
```

Comment: This is good but I still get something like 1:00:20.30, while I want for example 01:00:20.30. I tried to apply `{:0>8}.{:02.0f}` but it fails. Also `{%H:%M:%S}.{02.0f}` not working. Can I write it correctly in a quick way?

Comment: @Peter.k The `{:0>8}.{:02.0f}` approach should work as long as you wrap `timedelta(seconds=isec)` with `str(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but here's a 2021 answer with **f-strings** (modified from @Seb's original answer):

```py
def format_td(seconds, digits=3):
    isec, fsec = divmod(round(seconds*10**digits), 10**digits)
    return f'{timedelta(seconds=isec)}.{fsec:0{digits}.0f}'
```